# Can't access protected method from child class

Tags: java, inheritance, classloader

So, we have

```
public abstract class A{
    protected abstract String f();
}

public class B extends A{
     protected String f(){...}
}

public class C extends A{
    protected String f(){
         A b = (A) Class.forName("B", true, getClass().getClassLoader()).newInstance();
         return b.f();
}
```

This doesn't allow me to access `b.f()`, saying that `B.f()` is in the protected scope, however `f` was protected by `A`, and since `C` extends `A`, it should also get access to `f()`.

Comment: Why not create new instance like : A b = (A) new B(); ?

Comment: B is only available at runtime. If you really want to know, B is `com.android.okhttp.HttpsHandler`, and A is `URLStreamHandler`

Comment: You can solve your case via reflection, but it would be more helpful if you posted your *original* problem. Which method of `HttpsHandler` are you trying to call and why do you need it. See the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Consider opening a new question with your original problem.

Comment: don't you have a feeling you're doing something wrong? if so, why are you trying to make it worse?

Comment: Because that's the only way. The class is only available at runtime, and this reflection is how it is actually done in `URL`, which is in the same package as `UrlStreamHandler`. Oh well, I guess I can't use this functionality. My original problem is to make all HttpsConnections use my custom certificate. I wanted to do it by creating my own URLStreamHandler, which would delegate to default stream handlers to open connections, just do `setSSLSocketFactory` if the protocol is https. My custom `URLStreamHandler` would then be sent to URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory.

Comment: @doom777 I hope you go and ask how to resolve this problem, not just move your class to com.android.okhttp package

Comment: I just abandoned this path. I will simply provide my `URLStreamHandler` every time I want a secure URL, and to get a delegate URL connection inside the stream handler, I just build a new URL with the same spec with default stream handler, and take its connection. Less pretty, but it works and is best I can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.

If you want to access the B.f(), you should have the C class defined in the same package as B.

Comment: but this level of accessibility can be achieved by using no modifiers(known as "package private"). If a subclass that accesses protected methods must by in the same package does it means that package private and protected modifiers does the same? I think subclass that accesses protected methods can be in any package. Correct me if I'm not right.

Comment: You are correct. The answer try to solve the problem as it is stated in the question.

Comment: Now i see. But variable b is of type A, and instance of B() is casted to A. This moment is interesting why access is illegal

Comment: That is because the C class is defined in a different package and you cannot access other than public fields on an instance.

Answer (score 0):

No because the compiler does not know whether `b` is an instance of `B`, `C`, or other external classes.

Suppose there is a class `D` such that `D extends A` in another package. If `b` is an instance of `D` (the compiler does not know) `b.f()` should be forbidden if the access is `protected` (can't be accessed by classes in other packages).

Comment: @doom777 suppose now `b` is a `D`, where `D extends A` and is defined in another package with a `protected` `f()` method. Considering `D`,  `A` is in "another package", so `A` cannot access `protected` methods in `D`. However the compile doesn't know whether `b` is an `B`, `C` or `D`, so `b.f()` must be forbidden (in case `b` is an instance of `D`).

Comment: @doom777 The fact that `D` is not a subclass of `C` makes `f()` in `D` unavailable to `C`... =)

Comment: @doom777 `protected` in `D` is different from `protected` in `A`. In fact a subclass can always redefine the access modifier (as long as the access modifier isn't more restrictive). In this case I would consider the access modifiers to be "independent".